# I want to make many to many relationship using laravel Model

Tags: laravel

I am trying to make many to many relationships b/w three table I don't know how to make that please confirm me my relationship correct or not.

**Project table**

```
id | name
```

**user table**

```
id | name
```

**project_assign**

```
id | user_id | project_id
```

**User Model**

```
public function project_assign()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project_assign','project_assign','user_id','id');
}
```

**project_assign Model**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','Project_assign','user_id','id');
}
```

**Project Model**

```
public function project_assign()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project_assign','project_assign','project_id','id');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to make a relation in project_assign model. only Project and User will have relation,

**Project** Model

```
public function users(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','project_assign','project_id','user_id');
}
```

**User** Model

```
public function projects(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project','project_assign','user_id','project_id');
}
```

In **controller** you can get like this

```
User::with('projects')->get();
Project::with('users')->get();
```